# wordpress API: how to update custom meta box

Tags: php, wordpress, api

I've created a custom meta box, but i can't update that through api rest. This is my code. The var $_POST in a function save_custom_meta_box is always empty when I send a request.

Create meta box

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'adding_custom_meta_boxes', 10, 2 );
if (!function_exists('adding_custom_meta_boxes')) {
    function adding_custom_meta_boxes( $post_type, $post ) {
        add_meta_box(
            "demo-meta-box",
            "Custom Meta Box",
            "custom_meta_box_markup",
            "post",
            "side",
            "high",
            null
        );
    }
}
```

Storing Meta Data

```
add_action("save_post", "save_custom_meta_box", 10, 3);
function save_custom_meta_box($post_id, $post, $update)
{
    if(!current_user_can("edit_post", $post_id)){
        return $post_id;
    }

    if($post->post_type != "post"){
        return $post_id;
    }

    $meta_box_checkbox_value = "";

    if(isset($_POST["meta-box-checkbox"]))
    {
        $meta_box_checkbox_value = $_POST["meta-box-checkbox"];
    }

    update_post_meta($post_id, "meta-box-checkbox", $meta_box_checkbox_value);
}
```

SOLUTION:
Use action rest_after_insert_post.

```
add_action('rest_after_insert_post', 'wp_kama_rest_after_insert_post_type_action', 10, 3);
function wp_kama_rest_after_insert_post_type_action( $post, $request, $creating ) {

    if ($creating) {
        return;
    }
    
    $body = json_decode($request->get_body());
    if($body->metaBoxCheckbox)
    {
        update_post_meta($post->ID, "meta-box-checkbox", $body->metaBoxCheckbox);
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: Request: POST
{
    "meta-box-checkbox": "false"
}

$_POST["meta-box-checkbox"] is always empty.